# Place cursor between 2 points in text area on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor, textarea, editor

I'm adding some code to a text area on button click, I'd like to put the cursor in a specific point in the text area.

e.g. cursor goes here on button click

Here is the code I have currently, any help would be great.

html

```
<a href="#" class="button grey div">div</a>
<textarea id="editor" class="html-text" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

jquery

```
$(".div").click(function() {
    var caretPos = document.getElementById("editor").selectionStart;
    var textAreaTxt = $("#editor").val();
    var txtToAdd = '<div></div>';
    $("#editor").val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$("#editor").focus();
```

to give focus back to the textarea, and then

```
$("#editor")[0].setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
```

to place the cursor.

[setSelectionRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange)